# Misplaced \tikzmark

Tags: tables, tikzmark, luacode

In the next code, I hoped the `tikzmark` should be placed on the tabular black lines, but there is a drift.

The main goal is to put a phantom tikz mark in each corner of each cell of a table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xparse,luacode}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{TabTikzCount}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\TabTikzMark}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]\noalign{\setcounter{TabTikzCount}{1}}%
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]%
        }{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}}
\makeatother

\begin{luacode}
function row (s)
    a = "\\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}"
    for i = 1,s-1
    do
    a=a.."\\strut\\hfill\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}"..i.."}}&\\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{"
    end
    a=a.."\\strut\\hfill\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}"..s.."}}"
    tex.print (a)
    print (a)
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\Row}[1]{%
\directlua{row(#1)}
\stepcounter{TabTikzCount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\TabTikzMark*{4}\hline
a&z&a&d\TabTikzMark{4}\hline
a&z&a&d\TabTikzMark{4}\hline
\end{tabular}

\foreach \j in {A,B,C} {%
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
        \node at (pic cs:\j\i) {\tiny \j\i} ;
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In `\TabTikzMark` you have `\Row{3}` hardcoded, I think it should be `\Row{#2}`.  If I make that change, then I get the nodes in the right places.

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions about this code but you haven't given any top level description of the intent here, the interaction with tabular seems flawed but hard to correct without knowing what the code is trying to do

Comment: @LoopSpace Thank you, I have forgotten this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Put a tikz mark in each corner of each case of a table. I will add it to this question, I did it for some others, followin your advice.

Comment: but if you just want the marks on the outer corners of the table why are you adding marks within the table? you could put a mark at each corner of a box without knowing whether the content of a box is a table or a word or an image etc

Comment: My english is not very good : I want a tikzmark on each corner of each cell of the table : on each intersection between horizontal and vertical line. It's done thanks to you. Still the first parasite line because one cell is unfortunatly declare at the begining ans can't be phantomise with the egreg's trick. For now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding white space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xparse,luacode}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{TabTikzCount}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\TabTikzMark}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]\noalign{\setcounter{TabTikzCount}{1}}%
        \Row{3}%
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]%
        }{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]%
        \Row{3}%
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}}
\makeatother

\begin{luacode}
function row (s)
    a = "\\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}"
    for i = 1,s-1
    do
    a=a.."\\strut\\hfill\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}"..i.."}}&\\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{"
    end
    a=a.."\\strut\\hfill\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}"..s.."}}"
    tex.print (a)
    print (a)
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\Row}[1]{%
\directlua{row(#1)}%
\stepcounter{TabTikzCount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\TabTikzMark*{4}\hline
a&z&a&d\TabTikzMark{4}\hline
a&z&a&d\TabTikzMark{4}\hline
\end{tabular}

\foreach \j in {A,B,C} {%
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
        \node at (pic cs:\j\i) {\tiny \j\i} ;
}}

\end{document}
```